# CruiseControl.NET and Visual Studio Async CTP

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, async-ctp

I have been signed a task to set up CruiseControl.NET for our project. Everything went fine until I stomped on the fact that we were using Async CTP. My questions are following:

- Are there any options for calling Async CTP build machine other than through Visual Studio? (Do the preprocessing manually without using VS.)
- How to force CruiseControl.NET to build a project with Async CTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Cruise Control .NET, but I'm familiar with how the Async CTP works.

The CTP includes an CTP-capable compiler. You *should* be able to install the CTP on your build machine, which will allow for it to compile Async .NET code.

If the CTP installer requires Visual Studio, you should be able to install VS, then the CTP, and then uninstall VS while still leaving a CTP-capable compiler on your machine.

This is similar to how I would expect someone to use the CTP in conjunection with compile-on-demand scenarios for ASP.NET.

Comment: A very similar solution has worked for me. I took the compiler from my machine which had VS and CTP and used it to replace the one on the build machine.

Answer (score 1):

The trick that worked for me was to take the msbuild from my pc where I had VS with async ctp installed and replace the msbuild on the build machine at the build server.

Answer (score 0):

I use another build server tool, TeamCity, but since it all comes down to MSBuild, I think it should work the same.

I had the same doubts about the compatibility with the Async CTP, since it adds keywords to .NET itself, but after trying it, it seems that all you need to do is reference the AsyncCtpLibrary.dll in your project, and make sure that the DLL gets to your build server. I suggest including it in your version control system, ex. Subversion, so the reference is relative to your project root and will automatically be at the right place on your build server.

This way you don't have to "trick" your computer to install the full package.

Comment: That somehow didnt work for me. I ve solved it with the build machine replacement as I say in a comment below.

Comment: Santos - What do you mean 'replace MSBuild' ?? You copy over the whole folder C:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 ? Msbuild is just an .exe file - what do you mean you copied it to remote server ? x86 / x64 server ? What exactly did you do ?